# Python Webscraping Selenium Pop Up Youtube

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have been trying to web scrape a youtube video but each time I launch the google driver I get presented with a pop-up. I tried to work around it by trying to make selenium to press for me. I was able with the first one. But the second one was more tricky.

- I tried to press it using XPath, both the normal and the full detailed one
- I then tried to press it using name finder. But no success either.

Is there another workaround or is there something wrong or what I can improve with my code? To clarify, I have problems with the second image (i agree button). The goal of this code is to sort the comments by new. Is there a better way to do it in selenium?

code:

```
import sys, unittest, time, datetime
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import InvalidArgumentException
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--lang=en')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\caspe\OneDrive\Documents\Övrigt\Kodning\Email\chromeDriver\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EV6PLN_8RBw")
time.sleep(5)

driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/ytd-app/ytd-popup-container/paper-dialog/yt-upsell-dialog-renderer/div/div[3]/div[1]/yt-button-renderer")[0].click()
time.sleep(5)

#This Doesn't work
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'I agree')]")
for btn in buttons:
    btn.click()
```

[image: Was able to press this one]
[image: But not this one]

Comment: good question, i tried to use css selectors, didnt work out either, you might need to use an explicit wait, to ensure it is in view

Comment: Unfortunately no luck there either. 
 the command: wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#introAgreeButton"))) didn't even find the object either.

Comment: Is it any iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can automate pressing it with your mouse:

```
pyautogui.moveTo(100, 150) # Move the mouse to XY coordinates.
pyautogui.click()
```

I hope this is helpful!